# plot multiple 3d lines

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot 2 lines in a single 3D  graph. I have 3 coordinate data matrices for each line.

This is my code:

```
    plot3(pathline_x1 , pathline_y1 , pathline_z1,'g');
    hold on
    plot3(pathline_x1,pathline_y1,pathline_z1,'r');  
    hold on
```

From some reason it plots only the last one. Can someone help me plot both lines?

Comment: You are plotting the *exact* same line, so it overwrites it. Try plotting the second with `x` and `y` interchanged and you'll see both lines. Also only one call to `hold on` is sufficient.

Comment: Hi adrian first thanks for the help.                                                                             Second I actually fix it and it still not working.
I fixed the code and now I get an error and this picture.
That's the code and this is the error I receive:  <code>

Comment: sorry I'm new here trying to follow the rules...    <pre>     <Error using plot
String argument is an unknown option.
Error in Ex_2_ques_1 (line 88)
        plot(pathline_x2,  pathline_y2 , pathline_z2, 'r'); >

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1 2];y=x;
figure;plot(x,y,'r');hold on;plot(x,y,'b');
```

This will overwrite your line, since `x` and `y` are exactly equal.

[image]

To see it actually works, plot two different lines:

```
figure;plot(x,y,'r');hold on;plot(x,y+2,'b');
```

[image]

Note that I have called `hold on` only once, since it will hold *all* plots within the figure until you call `hold off` or open a new figure using `figure`.